# How to fix "flutter doctor --android-licenses" java error? Without android studio

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-licenses

When I try to accept android licenses using command `flutter  doctor --android-licenses` a java error is thrown.

Here is java error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

Here is my output for `flutter doctor -v`:

[image: flutter doctor -v output]

How can I solve above java error?

Note: I want to solve this problem without using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happened because when running `flutter  doctor --android-licenses`, it implicitly running the sdk tools which is only works with `JDK 8` (afaik, correct me if I'm wrong).

So, you need to install `JDK 8` and set your `JAVA_HOME` to your `JDK 8` installation path.